# Alternative derivation for Lagrange interpolation error

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation-theory, lagrange-interpolation

I am reading the book, Computational Differential Equations by Erikson, Estep, Hansbo and Johnson.
My problem setting is as follows -

Given the nodal points $\zeta_0, \zeta_1 \in [a, b]$, and the Lagrange polynomials, $$\lambda_0(x) = \frac{x - \zeta_1}{\zeta_0 - \zeta_1}, \lambda_1(x) = \frac{x - \zeta_0}{\zeta_1 - \zeta_0},$$ the Lagrange interpolant of a function $f(x)$ is
$$\Pi f(x) = \lambda_0f(\zeta_0) + \lambda_1f(\zeta_1) \; \; (*)$$
The error is derived to be
$$|\Pi f(x) -f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|(x-\zeta_0)(x - \zeta_1)| \underset{\zeta \in [a, b]}{\mathrm{max}}   |f''(\zeta)|$$
In contrast to the usual proof that invokes Rolle's theorem repeatedly to derive the error estimate,  here the proof for $\zeta_0 < x < \zeta_1$ proceeds as follows:

Expand $f(\zeta_0), f(\zeta_1)$ around $x$ in Taylor's series:
$$f(\zeta_0) = f(x) + f'(x) (\zeta_0 -x) + f''(c_0) (\zeta_0 -x)^2/2$$
$$f(\zeta_1) = f(x) + f'(x) (\zeta_1 -x) + f''(c_1) (\zeta_1 -x)^2/2$$

Plugging these expansions into  (*), and using
$$\lambda_0(x) + \lambda_1(x) = 1, \;\;(\zeta_0 -x)\lambda_0 + (\zeta_1 - x) \lambda_1 = 0 \;\; (**),$$

$$\Pi f(x) - f(x) = 1/2 [f''(c_0) (\zeta_0 -x)^2\lambda_0(x) + f''(c_1) (\zeta_1 -x)^2\lambda_1(x) ] \; \; (**)$$

Now taking absolute value and simplifying  the inequalities, we use $|x - \zeta_0| = x - \zeta_0$  but $|x - \zeta_1| = \zeta_1 - x$ due to the position of x between $\zeta_0, \zeta_1$ to get
$$|\Pi f(x) -f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|(x-\zeta_0)(x - \zeta_1)| \underset{\zeta \in [a, b]}{\mathrm{max}}   |f''(\zeta)|$$.

**My question starts here:**
Now this is clear, but the authors then leave as exercise (labelled as "hard") the proof of the analogous result
$$|\Pi f(x) -f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{6}|(x-\zeta_0)(x - \zeta_1)(x - \zeta_2)| \underset{\zeta \in [a, b]}{\mathrm{max}}   |f'''(\zeta)|$$

for the case of quadratic Lagrange basis functions $\lambda_0(x), \lambda_1(x), \lambda_2(x)$ with nodal points $\zeta_0, \zeta_1, \zeta_2$.

If I assume that $\zeta_0 < x < \zeta_1 < \zeta_2$, and try expanding in Taylor's series around $x$, and extend the identities (**) to eliminate $f'(x),  f''(x)$,  I end up with

$$|\Pi f(x) -f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{6}|(x-\zeta_0)(x - \zeta_1)(x - \zeta_2)| \underset{\zeta \in [a, b]}{\mathrm{max}} |f'''(\zeta)| \; g(x) $$
where $$g(x) = \left[ \dfrac{(x-\zeta_0)^2}{(\zeta_1-\zeta_0)(\zeta_2 - \zeta_0)} + \dfrac{(x-\zeta_1)^2}{(\zeta_1-\zeta_0)(\zeta_2 - \zeta_1)} + \dfrac{(x-\zeta_2)^2}{(\zeta_2 -\zeta_0)(\zeta_2 - \zeta_1)} \right]$$

The last expression $g(x)$ is definitely greater than 1 for $\zeta_0 < x < \zeta_1$!

I think there is some clever trick that I probably need to introduce in choosing what to expand around what point, but I am not able to get it.

Could somebody suggest  how to proceed and  derive the estimate in this case ?